# combine multiple regex patterns VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba

Im using the below code to extract sizes from excel cells, which has 7 different patterns..

The below code is for extracting OZ sizes however, i need to do the same ml and gram (g). Hence, the way i wrote the code will be very lengthy.

| Value | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Size:0.028 oz x 5 | 0.028 oz x 5 |
| Size:6x0.04 oz + 30 oz | 6 x0.04 oz |
| Size:8 x 0.03 oz | 8 x 0.03 oz |
| Size:2 x 0.07 oz | 2 x 0.07 oz |
| Size:5 x 0.028 oz | 5 x 0.028 oz |
| Size:0.028 ozx5 | 0.028 ozx5 |
| Size:0.028 oz | 0.028 oz |
| Size:30.00 oz | 30 .00 oz |
| Size:2 * 0.07 oz | 2 * 0.07 oz |
| Size:0.028 oz * 5 | 0.028 oz * 5 |
| Size:2*0.07 oz | 2 *0.07 oz |
| Size:0.028 oz*5 | 0.028 oz*5 |
| Size:3.00 oz | 3 .00 oz |
| Size:3.00 oz | 3 .00 oz |
| Color:01UNIVERSA#||#Size:1.00 oz | 1 .00 oz |
| Lancôme Effacil Eye Makeup Remover, 4.2 Fl. Oz. | 0 . oz |
| Confidence In A Cleanser, 1 fl. oz, Travel Size | 1 fl. oz |

```css
Function getozv1(str As String)
    Dim n As Long, unit As String, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object
    
    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    getsize = vbNullString
    cnt = 0
    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,2}\sx\s[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)" 'for Size:2 x 0.5 oz
          
        
        If .test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            'resize the nums array to accept the matches
            ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
            'get measurement unit
            unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
            'populate the nums array with the matches
            
            For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                cnt = cnt + 1
            Next n
            
            If cnt > 1 Then
            getozv1 = "Set"
            Else
            'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
            getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
           
            End If
                        
        End If
        
        If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,2}x[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)" ''for no space Size:2x0.5 oz
        
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
        
        If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)\sx\s[0-9]{1,2}" 'for Size:0.028 oz x 5/ 0.8g
                
        'pattern2 without space [0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)x[0-9]{1,2}
        
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
        
        If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)x[0-9]{1,2}" 'for without Size:0.028 oz x 5/ 0.8g
                
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
        
        If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,2}\s\*\s[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)" 'Size:2 * 0.07 oz
                
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
        
        If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,2}\*[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)" 'no space Size:2*0.07 oz
                
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
                
        If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)\s\*\s[0-9]{1,2}" 'Size:0.028 oz * 5
                
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
        
        If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "[0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)\*[0-9]{1,2}" 'Size:0.028 oz*5
                
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
         If Not .test(str) Then
        
         .Pattern = "([0-9.\-*?/]{1,5}\s*(fl oz|Fl oz|fl. oz|fl.oz|oz|Oz|oZ|OZ\s+)){1,3}" 'base pattern
                
            If .test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
                'get measurement unit
                unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
                'populate the nums array with the matches
                
                For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                    nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next n
                
                If cnt > 1 Then
                getozv1 = "Set"
                Else
                'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
                getozv1 = LCase(Application.Sum(nums) & " " & unit)
               
                End If
                            
            End If
            
        End If
        
    End With
End Function
```

How to do we do this in a efficient way? can we combine these 7 patterns without impacting result/accuracy?

Or is there better way to do this?

Few examples for gram(g) ml

| Data | Expected result | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MamaDerma Stretch Mark Repair Cream - 100 ml | 100 ml |  |
| MamaDerma Stretch Mark Prevention Oil - 60 ml | 60 ml |  |
| Supermood Egoboost Moisture Kick Serum, 30ml | 30ml |  |
| Size:15 mL x3 | 15 ml x3 |  |
| Size:Mini Size - 7 g | 7 g |  |
| Type: 4 g Ampoule 40 g Rubber™ Mask with Moisturizing Hyaluronic Acid | Set | multiple sizes |
| Size:Standard Size- 5.0 g-golden pink | 5.0 g |  |
| Size:Mini Size - 7 g | 7 g |  |
| Size:Standard Size - 21 g | 21 g |  |
| Size:Mini Size Translucent - 5.4 g | 5.4 g |  |
| 05浅色/陶瓷白 7g | 7 g |  |
| Size: 28ml*4 | 28ml*4 |  |
| Size:20g*10 | 20g*10 |  |
| Size: (2ml+3ml）×4ml | Set | multiple sizes |
| Size4*18ml | 4*18ml |  |
| Size: 27g*5ea | 27g*5 |  |
| Size 4.6ml × 4 | 4.6ml × 4 |  |
| Size 4 x 4.6ml | 4 x 4.6ml |  |
| Size 4.6ml×4 | 4.6ml×4 |  |
| Size 4x4.6ml | 4x4.6ml |  |
| Size: 28ml * 4 | 28ml * 4 |  |
| Size:20g * 10 | 20g * 10 |  |
| 27mlx3 片 | 27mlx3 |  |
| Size: 12 x 1.5g | 12 x 1.5g |  |
| Size: 12x1.5g | 12x1.5g |  |

Comment: yes it will be in the same format (pattern).. if you need plz wait i need sometime

Comment: oh thank you for letting me know will do it in sometime

Comment: @QHarr added the sample plz take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not too difficult to develop a single regex that works for all of your examples.

I suggest:

```
Option Explicit
'set reference to Microsoft VBcript Regular Expressions 5.5
Function getAmt(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection
    Const sPat As String = "(?:\d+\s*[x*]\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?=(g|ml|(?:fl)?\.?\s*oz))\1(?:\s*[×x*]\s*\d+)?"
    
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    
    Set MC = .Execute(S)
        Select Case MC.Count
            Case 0
                getAmt = "no amount"
            Case 1
                getAmt = MC(0)
            Case Is > 1
                getAmt = "Set"
        End Select
End With
        
End Function
```

[image]

It works on all of your examples (except for the obvious typos)

Here is a detailed explanation of the regex:

### Get Amts and Quantities from String

```
(?:\d+\s*[x*]\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?=(g|ml|(?:fl)?\.?\s*oz))\1(?:\s*[×x*]\s*\d+)?
```

Options: Case insensitive

- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:\d+\s*[x*]\s*)?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match a single character from the list “x*”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[x*]`
  - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:\.\d+)?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match the character “.” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\.`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead); keep text matched by nested capturing groups when backtracking beyond the lookround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=(g|ml|(?:fl)?\.?\s*oz))`

  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(g|ml|(?:fl)?\.?\s*oz)`

    - [Match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `g`

      - [Match the character “g” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `g`
    - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `ml`

      - [Match the character string “ml” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `ml`
    - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(?:fl)?\.?\s*oz`

      - [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:fl)?`

        - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
        - [Match the character string “fl” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `fl`
      - [Match the character “.” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\.?`

        - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
      - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

        - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
      - [Match the character string “oz” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `oz`
- [Match the same text that was most recently matched by capturing group number 1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:\s*[×x*]\s*\d+)?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match a single character from the list “×x*”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[×x*]`
  - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: Wow its working amazingly!! Thank you for the detailed explanation..

Comment: @Linga Also, please note that in one spot of the pattern, there is `[×x*]`.  Your data source uses both.  But I only changed it in the one spot.  If this use of `×` might be more prevalent, you should consider changing other `[x]` to `[×x*]`

Comment: Sure thank you again.. such a wonderful learning for me :)

Comment: Ron: Need your help on this example  Size:12 x 2 packettes 0.02 oz/ 0.75 g | Size:50 x 0.04 oz/ 1.25 mL | Size:3 x 1.7 oz/ 50.28 mL.. Here its given same size into two different UOM can we extract anyone by excluding Oz ? Is this doable?

Comment: @Linga Not with the same regex. I suggest you write some extra code in the `Case > 1` section so that, instead of just returning `Set`,  **1.** Determine if there is more than one UOM. **2.** Return the one you want.

Comment: Sure im trying that only :)

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why you want to consolidate seven regular expressions into one. It may or may not be more "efficient" (how are you planning to test that?), it will certainly be much more difficult to maintain.

The first thing I suggest you do is set up a regression test environment so you can make sure that any changes you make in the future do not break the existing tests. In VBA, that would look something like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestParse()

    ' Two dimensional array containing the test values and the expected results
    Dim testdata(1 To 25, 1 To 2) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim result As String
    
    testdata(1, 1) = "MamaDerma Stretch Mark Repair Cream - 100 ml"
    testdata(1, 2) = "100 ml"
    
    testdata(2, 1) = "MamaDerma Stretch Mark Repair Cream - 60 ml"
    testdata(2, 2) = "60 ml"

    'add more values & expected results
    
    testdata(25, 1) = "Size: 12x1.5g"
    testdata(25, 2) = "12x1.5g"

    
    ' Test all values
    For i = LBound(testdata, 1) To UBound(testdata, 1)
        result = Parse(testdata(i, 1))
        Debug.Print testdata(i), result, IIf(testdata(i, 2) = result, "PASS", "FAIL")
    Next i

End Sub

' Function to parse values
Function Parse(ByVal toParse As String) As String

    ' Code to parse values goes here

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. As im writing lengthy lines, just want to improve a bit